# How to add a border to widget titles in Blogger?

Tags: html, css, widget, blogs, blogger

So I'm a user of Blogger, and I would just like to ask how do you add a border around the title of each widget/gadget? I place widgets in the sidebar, like About Me, Follow Us, etc., and I want to place a border around them, like in this picture. I only know how to make the widget titles have the same font and everything, so does anyone know how I can place a border?

Widget with borders

[image: xxx]

Comment: could you show your current html?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting each widget within a div, and adding css for the divs to have padding.

For example:

```
<div class=widget">
 widget here
</div>

<style>
    .widget{
       padding:5px;
    }
</style>
```

Something like that should work. Let me know if it does not.
Additionally, posting your code as an edit within the question would make it a lot easier to help solve your problem.